# Are the domain and range of a vector field vector quantities?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I have been given the following question:

"Is this statement true?: A vector field is a function where the domain and the range are vector quantities."

I'm unsure of the answer; as the values on each axis can only be scalar quantities, but together, they can form a vector quantity in the plane (at least, this is my understanding of it).

Am I thinking correctly and the answer is that it is not true?

Comment: Depends who's asking.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is true if one considers vector fields on $\mathbb R^n$.

A way to define vector fields in $\mathbb R^n$ is precisely

*Definition:* A smooth vector field on $\mathbb R^n$ is a smooth function $v:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$.

This definition generalizes in many ways. For instance, given a smooth submanifold $M\subset \mathbb R^n$

*Definition:* A smooth vector field on $M$ is a smooth function $v:M\to \mathbb R^n$ such that for any $p\in M$ the vector $v(p)$ belongs to the tangent space of $M$.

More generally, given an abstract manifold, you can define its tangent space $TM$ as an collection of spaces $V_p$ each one attached to $p\in M$. Then a vector field is a function $v:M\to TM$ such that $v(p)\in V_p$.

Vector fields are first used to compute directional derivatives of funcions on $M$. Thus, a very general generalization of vector field is given as the set of derivation over the modulus of the differentiable function. At this point you can forget about manifolds and speak about derivations over a modulus on a ring.

Wikipedia is a good soource for all the above definitions.